# Short code not working in boostrap modal dont no why?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I am trying to put a pluign into a short code it works on the page but when i try to insert it into a modal popup it doesnt render correct at all.

```
<div id="thanks" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Redeem Points</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    <?php echo do_shortcode['go_greenredempoints'];?>
    </div><!-- End of Modal body -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal content -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal dialog -->
</div><!-- End of Modal -->
```

This is my show form routine in my plugin :

```
function show_form(){

echo "<form class='form-horizontal'  class='contact' name='redemmpointsForm' id='redemmpointsForm' >";
 echo " <div class='form-group'>";
 echo "<h3>You may only redeem the maxium points of : <?php echo $maxpoints;?></h3>";
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='playerid' value='<?php echo $playerId;;?>' />";
   echo "<input type='number'  valuemax='<?php echo $maxpoints;?>' name='points' id='points' class='form-control' placeholder='How many points do you wish to redeem.' />";
  echo "<label class='control-label col-md-4' for='Comments'>Comments?</label>";
   echo "<input type='text' name='comments' />";

   echo "     </div>";
    echo "    <div class='form-group'>";
    echo "            <div class='col-md-6'>";

     echo "                <input type='button' class='btn btn-success' name='submit' id='submit' Text='Submit'>";
   echo "   <a     <a href='#' class='btn' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</a>";

       echo "         </div>";
      echo "      </div>";
echo "</form>";


}
```

and I defined my shortcode as

```
add_shortcode( 'go_greenredempoints', 'gs_redeemplugin' );

function gs_redeemplugin() {
    ob_start();
    show_form();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

?>

Comment: It is not clear how all of these pieces fit together

Comment: i solved it anyway took it out put it into a plugin and works wordpress weird sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, change

```
<?php echo do_shortcode['go_greenredempoints'];?>
```

with

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[go_greenredempoints]');?>
```